# Adding text to instfiles page in NSIS installer

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm writing an NSIS installer, and want to add some text to the instfiles page while a background process is runnning silently. EG:

```
SetOutPath $INSTDIR\Temp
File "C:\InstallationFiles\IIS_Configure.cmd" 
OUTPUTTEXT "Configuring IIS..."
nsExec::Exec '"$INSTDIR\Temp\IIS_Configure.cmd"'
```

(Where OUTPUTTEXT is currently pseudo code)

I would then want the output on screen for the user to be:

```
Output folder: C:\Program Files\Install Folder\Temp
Extract: IIS_Configure.cmd
Configuring IIS...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DetailPrint](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#detailprint) if you want to add a line to the log window and you can use `SetDetailsPrint` to turn off messages from other commands if you want...